# Invite Facebook friends only shows notification in Facebook app not in browser

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to Invite my Facebook friends with the app playstore URL to install. I am using following code for Facebook Invite.

```
AppInviteContent content = new AppInviteContent.Builder()
            .setApplinkUrl(appLinkUrl)
            .setPreviewImageUrl(previewImageUrl)
            .build();
    AppInviteDialog.show(this, content);
```

Now, my problem is, My friend is getting notification only when he has facebook app but not in browser. Please help me what should I use to get notification in both app and browser. Is it possible to post it as a message?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/overview: _“App Invites notifications will only show up in the recipient's Facebook notifications on mobile platforms, not on desktop web.”_

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it but I believe you can send as message using `.setDestination(AppInviteContent.Builder.Destination.MESSENGER)`